# Can I install two instances (2012 and 2015) of TFS on the same server

Tags: tfs, server, installation, tfs-2015

We are looking at upgrading, but management does not want to buy another server.

We currently have TFS 2012 installed.  Can I install TFS 2015 beside it or will that create a problem?

I would imagine I would at least need to configure a different port for TFS web.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you cannot. The installer for 2015 will force you to remove the 2012 Application Tier.

Your [SQL Server database server will be shareable as long as it's a version that supported by both 2012 and 2015](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/requirements) (SQL Server 2012 (minimum SP1)). And as long as both instances [have a different database label configured](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee248709(v=vs.120).aspx).

[image]