# Can two instances of the same TFS version share a data layer

Tags: tfs, tfs-migration

My question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38770789/can-i-install-two-instances-2012-and-2015-of-tfs-on-the-same-server/38771756#38771756) but in my case I am wondering can two of the SAME version of TFS (2013) share a data layer. I cannot find any documentation stating that it is ok or, alternatively, that it will cause issues.

I am wondering if this would be a viable option for testing setting up a new instance of the server but I do not know what issues having two TFS instances connected to the same data layer / database may cause (or if its even possible).

Comment: Do you want 2 TFS app tiers with 1 sql server?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk yes, I am wondering if that is even possible, and if so what are the implications. Either concurrently or swapping between the two. The situation would be for testing.

Comment: do you want it on the same server or in 2 servers?

Comment: BTW - what do you mean for testing? if you will create a work item in one of then, he will be exist also in the second, because the sql data it's 1 server for both.

Comment: The app tiers would be on two different servers. By testing I mean most read-only operations to make sure connectivity is working ok but possibly also creating some new work items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate answer to your question is, "Yes". However, it's **not** what you want. You can configure multiple application tiers pointing to the same database; that's how you enable high availability/failover scenarios.

For testing purposes, you should create a second set of infrastructure.

Comment: Thanks. That was my assumption but I wanted to verify before ruling that out as a testing option.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/install/install-2013/config-tfs-advanced?view=tfs-2013 and what you are talking about is the "Server Database Label". It mentions:

> In Server Database Label, type a label string, which is then embedded into all three of the default database names.
>
> This technique enables you to use a single instance of SQL Server to host multiple configuration databases.

As other have mentioned, this might not be a good idea for a test environment though.